# Storing / retrieving parts of an xml document with mysql, php, and simpleXML

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, simplexml

I'm taking an xml document down from a partner API and I'd like to store the separate nodes into a mysql database so I can rebuild it with specific nodes.  I absolutely do not want to parse out the complete document into the database as all I care about are the IDs and the individual nodes in total.

So for example:

```
<list>
<child>20-30 grandchildren</child>
<child></child>
<child></child>
...
<child></child>
</list>
```

I'd like to be able to put the  blocks into a mysql database and then restore them.  That's where I'm falling down:  I use simple_xml to get the node and I use REPLACE to add it as a text, but I'm not sure how to them restore it back to .  For an array, I'd serialize and than unserialize but that fails here.

Is there an obvious method I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried serializing a simple_xml object?

Comment: @Briedis: Yes, that was my problem  -- while you can serialize an simple xml object you can't unserialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serialize SimpleXMLElement objects to XML with [`asXML()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) then you can load the document normally with [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

You cannot serialize SimpleXMLElement with serialize(), it will not work as expected.